# Type Error con la sentencia raise

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de escribir una función muy simple que vi en el libro "Aprende a pensar como un programador con python":

```
def elige_numero():
    x = input("Escriba un número: ")
    if x == str(17):
        raise('ErrorNumeroMalo', 'El 17 es malevolo')
    return x
```

El problema es que cuando en el `input` pongo el número 17 me da el error:

> TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException

¿Alguien sabe que paso y cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: He ido a ver el libro y la verdad es que es bastante vago en cuanto a este tema. Se limita a decir literalmente "ErrorNumeroMalo es un nuevo tipo de excepción que hemos inventado para esta aplicación."... Pero parece que no dice nada de como se ha "inventado". Para mi el entrecomillar `ErrorNumeroMalo` como si fuera una cadena genera aún mas confusión si cabe. No termino de entender el voto negativo que se ha dado a esta pregunta, la duda visto lo visto es comprensible para alguien que empieza...Maha el libro usa Python 2, lo digo porque puedes encontrate con incompatibilidades con Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que la excepción `ErrorNumeroMalo` no está definida (al menos no en el código que presentas). Así que como no existe, el intérprete piensa que quizás has escrito mal la excepción que estas tratando de lanzar.

La forma de solucionarlo es definir la excepción. Generalmente se hace con una clase que hereda de la clase `BaseException`, como lo indica el intérprete. Dentro del ámbito de tu script, creo que algo así funcionaría:

```
class ErrorNumeroMalo(BaseException):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
```

Y tu script se vería algo así:

```
def elige_numero():
    x = input("Escriba un número: ")
    if x == str(17):
        raise ErrorNumeroMalo("El 17 es malévolo")
    return x
```

Puedes consultar la [documentación oficial de BaseException](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=baseexception#BaseException), ya sabes, solo para saber un poco más. También puedes consultar, en la [documentación oficial de Python, como crear tus propias excepciones](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions).